# Making JavaSciptLint more configurable

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using mvim with plugin JavaScriptLint. It works great.

However sometimes I work on jQuery or other JavaScript libraries and every single time I save the file, I get tons of warning and cursor moves to the very first warning.

What I would like to have is some way to turn this feature On or off. Something like

```
:set enableJavaScriptLint
:set disableJavaSCriptLint
```

My [vimrc file is here](http://github.com/neerajdotname/vim/blob/master/vimrc). And the [plugin is here](http://github.com/neerajdotname/vim/blob/master/plugin/javaScriptLint.vim#L14) . Notce at line number 14 the plugin autodetects if jsl command is present then it gets enabled. I guess I need to write some function to enable or disable that call.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you have in mind, but
you can remove the autocommand and call the function manually or replace it with a shortcutkey maybe like this:

map <F11> :call JavascriptLint()

you then have to remember to first save the file, and only call it on *.js files though...

Or, you could fix all warnings...it'll stop complaining too ;-)